# speed up split query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a string like below:

```
       R#4039,4040,3508,3512,1006,4506,4514,4011,4035,4513,4518,2009,4012,1998,4037;FF#3007,2018,1005,4515,4020,4027,4029,1503,4516,1999,2003,4026,2002,4007,2011,1004,3006,4519
```

I want to split my string and add a random Id and the output I want is like this:

```
name    id
4515    1234562
2002    1234562
1998    1234561
4514    1234561
3007    1234562
1005    1234562
4516    1234562
1999    1234562
4007    1234562
3006    1234562
4519    1234562
4012    1234561
4011    1234561
4506    1234561
3512    1234561
4039    1234561
2018    1234562
1004    1234562
4037    1234561
4513    1234561
1006    1234561
4518    1234561
4020    1234562
1503    1234562
2003    1234562
4026    1234562
2009    1234561
3508    1234561
4027    1234562
4029    1234562
2011    1234562
4035    1234561
4040    1234561
```

I use the below query but it takes a lot of time(7 seconds) to response. I want to write the the query that gives me the same result but very fast.
my query is:

```
SELECT   distinct regexp_substr(TYPES,'[^,]+', 1,LEVEL),id FROM (


    select   REPLACE(regexp_substr(data ,'.+#', 1),'#','') AS NAME,REPLACE(regexp_substr(data ,'#.+', 1),'#','')AS TYPES , '123456'||id as id from (SELECT  LEVEL AS id, REGEXP_SUBSTR(REF_LEDGER_PROFIEL, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) AS data
   FROM (select 'R#4039,4040,3508,3512,1006,4506,4514,4011,4035,4513,4518,2009,4012,1998,4037;FF#3007,2018,1005,4515,4020,4027,4029,1503,4516,1999,2003,4026,2002,4007,2011,1004,3006,4519' as REF_LEDGER_PROFIEL from dual)
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(REF_LEDGER_PROFIEL, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)


) 
       CONNECT BY  REGEXP_SUBSTR(TYPES, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) is not null

       ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `DISTINCT`

Since you have `Name` unique for each group, add the common `prior + sys_guid` condition instead and remove the `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT regexp_substr(types, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
    ,id
FROM (
    SELECT replace(regexp_substr(data, '.+#', 1), '#', '') AS name
        ,replace(regexp_substr(data, '#.+', 1), '#', '') AS types
        ,'123456' || id AS id
    FROM (
        SELECT LEVEL AS id
            ,regexp_substr(ref_ledger_profiel, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) AS data
        FROM (
            SELECT 'R#4039,4040,3508,3512,1006,4506,4514,4011,4035,4513,4518,2009,4012,1998,4037;FF#3007,2018,1005,4515,4020,4027,4029,1503,4516,1999,2003,4026,2002,4007,2011,1004,3006,4519' AS ref_ledger_profiel
            FROM dual
            ) CONNECT BY regexp_substr(ref_ledger_profiel, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
        )
    ) CONNECT BY PRIOR name = name -- add This and 
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL --This
    AND regexp_substr(types, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Read [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2526535)  to know more about how it works.